# How to delete a collection with reference collections in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I Have this user model 
Which has blog model as reference and blog has comments collections as reference

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: {
        unique: true
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    website: {
      type: String
    },
    bio: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: "created_at",
      updatedAt: "updated_at"
    }
  }
);

userSchema.virtual("blogs", {
  ref: "blogs",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "author"
});
```

i want to delete blog data as well and any nested collection within blog collection too
how can i delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I got you right, this will help.

```
function deleteUserById(id){
    UserModel.findById(id, async (err, user) => {
        try{
            await deleteBlodById(user.blog._id);
            UserModel.findByIdAndRemove(id)
        }catch(e){
            throw e;
        }
    })
}
function deleteBlogById(id){
    BlogModel.findById(id, async (err, blog) => {
        // ... The pretty same thing like before, just delete 
    })
}
```

I hope that will help. If your question was like `Is there any function that automatically remove document and all its referenced documents` I cannot find anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this would do